# How to See foe specific string in a data frame using r?

Tags: r

I have two data frames, I want to look up each string in one dataframe compared to another and find the value.

Example:

df1:

```
test 
test1  
test20
test40,B6g4
name,bfg8
```

df2:

```
B6g4
bfg8
test
```

I want to find out if each value of df2 is present in any value of df1 and I also want to display those values where they appear.

I tried below which is throwing errors:

```
apply(df1, 1, function(r) any(r %in% df2))
```

Comment: Try `df1[[1]][df1[[1]] %in% df2[[1]]]` if there is only one column